# Running an exe with in a CLR method for Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, clr

I wrote a CLR method for sql server 2005 and trying to run an exe through it.

Here is the code:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static SqlString Function1()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe");
        return new SqlString("Some string ");
    }
```

After deploying when I try to run this CLR method in sql server 2005 it gives me following error:

```
 Msg 6522, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
    A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user defined routine or aggregate 'Function1': 
    System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.
    System.Security.SecurityException: 
       at UserDefinedFunctions.Function1()
```

Is it possible to run an exe like this ?

Comment: Actually I am trying to read images(.jpg) metadata, Images names will come through a db table. I am using System.Windows.Media.Imaging assembly methods to get this done. Since SqlServerProject doesn't support more assembliess I am trying to call exe for the image name, which will further read it's metadata

Comment: Hmmm, I see your problem. However, shelling out to exes from SQL Server is always going to be a potential security risk. Have you considered serving up the image data to your client app, then calling the `System.Windows.Media.Imaging` methods on the client instead?

Comment: What permission option did you use when creating the assembly in SQL server?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late for this posting, but in case others run into this, this is the answer I found:

The first thing I tried was th CLR approach (setting common language runtime) = true, but that didn't solve the problem. Reading more and looking a careful look at the error, I realized that SQL could not access some registry information on the machine because the ID underwhich the SQL server was running didn't have access to the key store.

So I added my user to the administrator's group and that fixed it. Took three hours to figure that out, so hopefully this will save someone time in the future.